# What font/typeface does Adobe Lightroom use for its UI? How do I recreate the font+kerning in Evernote?

Tags: font-identification, typefaces, adobe-lightroom

What font is used for the folder names (left pane) in the **Library Module** that all your photos are stored in?

[image]

Once I know the font, how do I get Evernote 6.25.1.9091 (Windows 10 Desktop version) to use that font and have the same **identical kerning** as Lightroom? Several fonts don't match Lightroom in terms of kerning like:

1. Segoe UI
2. Segoe
3. Adobe Clean
4. Myriad Pro

Here is what they look like in Evernote:

[image]

**Segoe UI** looks the closest, but the kerning is off and Evernote's "﹣" small hyphen minus (U+FE63) is super short when compared to Lightroom's. Does lightroom and Evernote have different kerning engines just like how Windows 10's File Explorer UI has a different kerning Engine for Segoe UI as well?

Comment: A screen-shot would help! But there are also [notes for the \[font-identification\] tag](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info) which are important to follow. Without any of the help, I'd guess at "Adobe Clean", a proprietary font.

Comment: That just looks like plain old Myriad, one of the most commonly used and most easily found fonts there.

Comment: The hyphen problem is mainly because adobe knows to use a en and em dash.

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom typeface, Adobe Clean. It's not available to license.
[image]

Comment: Can you explain Evernote and Lightroom's kerning discrepancy? Also if you look at the Adobe Clean "1" there are footer serifs at the bottom, but in the grey lightroom screenshot, there are none.